# How can I replace std::bind using lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, stdbind

```
auto dis_calculator =
        std::bind(&LaneTrackerImpl::calc_lane_distance, this,
                  std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, false, 0.0f,
                  std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4,
                  std::placeholders::_5, std::placeholders::_6);
```

I write code like this:

```
 auto lane_distance_calculator = [this](const Lane &lane1, const Lane &lane2,
                          bool disable_lane_start_distance_affection,
                          bool disable_lane_end_distance_affection,
                          DistanceMethod method, bool is_matching_phase)
{
    this->calc_lane_distance(
        lane1, lane2, false, 0.0f,
        disable_lane_start_distance_affection,
        disable_lane_end_distance_affection,
        method, is_matching_phase);
};
```

and the func merge_lanes use it:

```
merge_lanes(prob_thresh_list_, detected_lanes.lanes, tracked_lanes.lanes,
            result.lanes, next_track_id, detection_score_threshold_,
            lane_distance_calculator);
```

the error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘{anonymous}::LaneTrackerImpl::merge_lanes(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, std::vector<perception::Lane>&, std::vector<perception::Lane>&, std::vector<perception::Lane>&, size_t&, float&, {anonymous}::LaneTrackerImpl::merge(perception::LanePrediction&, perception::LanePrediction&, size_t)::<lambda(const perception::Lane&, const perception::Lane&, bool, bool, {anonymous}::LaneTrackerImpl::DistanceMethod, bool)>&)’
             lane_distance_calculator);
```

How can I solve it? it confused me for a long time.

Comment: I don't see `merge_lanes` in the code you provided.

Comment: Also, I don't see a closing '}'.

Comment: The code you posted is correct if we don't account for the missing `}`. I think the error you got is from somewhere else in your code, more specifically the things you added in the lambda just after.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  Try this instead:

```cpp
auto dis_calculator = [this](const Lane &lane1, const Lane &lane2,
                              bool disable_lane_start_distance_affection,
                              bool disable_lane_end_distance_affection,
                              DistanceMethod method, bool is_matching_phase)
{
    this->calc_lane_distance(
        lane1, lane2, false, 0.0f,
        disable_lane_start_distance_affection,
        disable_lane_end_distance_affection,
        method, is_matching_phase);
};
```